# How to open local web pages in Chrome on external SD card

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, external-sd, chrome-for-android

I wanted to be able to open local files in the Chrome browser. If I tap a local file (htm, rss) or paste a valid "file:" URI into Chrome it does not work when file is on external SD card. I am using Samsung S4 Android 5.0.1 (not rooted). I tested a few paths in the chrome browser and found works ok on internal SD card but that there is no read access to any data on the external SD card even the private data folder (I was expecting Chrome should have access to private folder on exteranl card??). Selecting a file E.g. **file:///mnt/sdcard/Documents/testarc.htm** on internal SD card works fine but paths like file:///storage/extSdCard will not show a directory.

I know that access restrictions were added to Android 5.x but don't applications have access to a private data folder (under /Android/data) on external SD card by default?

Does Chrome (com.android.chrome) have read access the **file:///storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/** ?

Is there a way to enable it?

I have two file manager apps installed - ES file explorer, Total Commander, and the is "Myfiles" app which came with the phone. If use ES file explorer or Myfiles the "open with" windows only lists Firefox not Chrome, or Samsung browsers. Choosing Firefox will open the web page file (htm) (even on external SD card), so is there a way to add other browsers to "open with" list?

In MS Windows file association was relatively simple using "registered file types" options. Is the Andriod equivalent?

Comment: For a non rooted phone this is the latest version of AOS that Samsung have released. I have read moving to an open source version the camera software is not as good as what I get with Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Chrome (com.android.chrome) have read access the file:///storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/ ?

One workaround I found is to download something (anything) and when you get the download prompt, choose to save to SD.  You can also choose from chrome settings `Settings -> Downloads -> Download location`.  Once you save one file, you will be prompted to grant the extSDcard permission.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I have found is using Total Commander (TC) and adding an entry setting which program to run with a specific extension in the TC configuration menu. To do this choose menu | configure | internal associations| new association. Define new settings for "htm" extension to open chrome (pick from "choose app" list) and tick box for "Parameters: content://url". When you select a file it passes a URI like content://com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander.files/storage/extSdCard/path/file.htm to Chrome browser. I noticed the file remains available as Chrome tab for several days, but then is not available until I open TC and pick the file again, so I assume it is a cached copy in TC of the original file.