# Chrome unable to read files from SD card

Tags: external-sd, 7.0-nougat, chromium

I have some HTML files in the SD card in my phone, which I want to open in Chrome. But, when I am entering the URL of those files in the Chrome's address bar with the `file:///` prefix, Chrome says **Access to the file was denied**. But, I have checked that Chrome has access to the storage. See this screenshot:

[image]

Please help me out.
I have Android 7.0 Nougat and please ask if any more information is required.

Comment: Are you able to save pages to your sd card when using Chrome?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Copy the file to the internal storage and check if Chrome can open it.

Comment: Yes, it can open from the internal storage.

Comment: It seems that Chrome does not have the permission to read the external storage although you have enabled it.

Comment: Try to use your file manager to open the file. If the "Open with" dialog box appears, select Chrome. Is Chrome able to open the file this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186478/how-to-open-local-web-pages-in-chrome-on-external-sd-card

Comment: if you type `file:///sdcard` in Chrome's address bar, does it send you to the internal or the external storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome can read file from the SD card folders it has access to. That folder, if you have set to download pages on the SD card, can be located by clicking Menu, then Downloads, then clicking on the gear. You have unrestricted access to that folder. But if you try to navigate to the parent folder, you will receive an `Access to the file was denied` message (if that folder is located on the SD card).

You can copy your files in that folder and read it from there. Or you can copy them to the internal storage and access the internal storage by typing `file:///sdcard/` from Chrome's address bar. The internal storage is not restricted and you can navigate to any folder.

Comment: You are right, Chrome can read and write from the `Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/download` folder in the SD card, but is unable to access it's parent directories. Thanks.

Comment: I have made a browser app of my own. In that app, everything is working fine, it is able to access the SD card. [See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vyiO.png). I can still remember that I haven't used any special permissions in that app.

Comment: @PuspamAdak I will have to check but if I remember correctly Firefox is also able to access the SD card in its entirety.

Comment: I know that using ADB, we can grant permissions to apps. So, is there any way to grant SD card reading permission to Chrome?

Comment: @PuspamAdak I am not sure if it is going to work or not on a non rooted phone. But you can try (if you have not already done it) the following command: `adb shell pm grant com.android.chrome android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. I have a rooted phone and with some Xposed modules, Chrome has full access to the SD card.

Comment: It didn't worked. Anyway, thanks for the information and for your involvement in this question.

Comment: Now, I am using my self-made browser for this purpose and some third-party HTML viewer apps for some more features.

Answer (score 0):

Am not a devloper but according to my experience -

Actually after an update you can check in your Android Apps Manager Settings you will see Chrome is only allowed to read only MEDIA files not EXTERNAL files. To fix this those who have APK EDITORS in your PC, you can edit the MANIFEST file to change the permission (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), otherwise please contact Google to inform this issue[image]